# Definition: A (linear) order type $\alpha$ being dense in a (linear) order type $\beta$ - resolving a (seeming) contradiction?

Tags: logic, order-theory, model-theory

I will use $\mathbf{\eta}$ and $\mathbf{\lambda}$ to respectively denote the order types of the rationals and the reals.  In the book  [Linear Orderings](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0488.04002), by Joseph Rosenstein (1982), he defines:

> **Definition 1:** An order type $\mathbf{\alpha}$ is dense in an order type $\mathbf{\beta}$ if any linear ordering $B$ of type $\mathbf{\beta}$ has a subset $A$ of type $\mathbf{\alpha}$ such that between any two elements of $B$ there is an element of $A$.

I assume by 'between' he means 'strictly between' as that is how he defined dense linear orders.  However, letting $C(\alpha)$ denote the order type of a completion of a linear ordering of type $\alpha$, in one of the exercises he asks the reader to show that if $\alpha$ is dense in $\beta$ then the respective completions $C(\alpha)$ and $C(\beta)$ are in fact the same (in the preceding exercise, where '$\preceq$' denotes the embeddability relation, we've already shown that $C(\alpha)\preceq C(\beta)$ when $\alpha\preceq \beta$).

The reason I consider this problematic is that this exercise implies that $C(\eta)=C(1+\eta)$, ($1+\eta$ being the same as $\eta$ but with a least element).  Am I mistaken and just missing something or is there something legitimately wrong here?  If the latter how can this be resolved?

Comment: What is the definition of $C(\alpha)$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman $C(\alpha)$ denotes the order type of some (and hence all) completions of orderings of type $\alpha$.

Comment: And a completion of $\alpha$ must have the property that $\alpha$ embeds as an  order dense subset in it? I have read the book, a long time ago, but haven't got it handy...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That is correct yes.  Every linear order embeds as a dense subset into its completion.

Comment: Can you sketch your argument why the stated theorem implies $C(\eta) = C(1+\eta)$? $\eta$ is not a completion of anything, so I don't see how it follows.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma There is an order-embedding of $\eta$ into $1+\eta$ which makes the image of $\eta$ dense in $1+\eta$, since any ordering of type $1+\eta$ must have a subset of type $\eta$.  From this the theorem then implies that $C(\eta)=C(1+\eta)$.

Comment: Isn't $C(\eta)=C(1+\eta)$ true? Because a complete linear order (indeed any complete lattice) must have a least element and a greatest element.

Comment: @bof Considered as lattices yes but in the context of linear orderings completeness refers to 'bounded-completeness' by which I mean that we only require sets bounded above to have a supremum (or equivalently, sets bounded below have an infimum).  For example ($\lambda$ as defined in the question): $\lambda$, $1+\lambda$, $\lambda+1$ and $1+\lambda+1$ are all complete linear orderings.  Of course the only one among these which is complete as a lattice is $1+\lambda+1$.

Comment: I think you mean "**nonempty** sets bounded above (below) have a supremum (infimum).

Comment: @bof Ah yes, thank you.  Apparently I cannot edit it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right, this is an error in the book. But new endpoints are the only obstruction. You can prove that if:

1. $\alpha$ is dense in $\beta$.
2. $\alpha$ has a least element if and only if $\beta$ has a least element.
3. $\alpha$ has a greatest element if and only if $\beta$ has a greatest element.

Then $C(\alpha) = C(\beta)$.